# some process are started through init even i am using systemd

Tags: systemd, init

When I do

```
ll /proc/1/exe
```

I get

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Oct 16 11:28 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

Which means i am running `systemd` daemon not `init`.

But when I list

```
ll /etc/init.d/
```

I still get some services which are running by `init` (stripped output),

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2269 Apr 22  2017 acpid*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  5336 Apr 15  2016 alsa-utils*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2014 Dec 29  2014 anacron*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4335 Mar 23  2018 apparmor*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2802 Jan  3  2018 apport*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2134 Jul  7  2015 autofs*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2401 Nov  5  2015 avahi-daemon*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2968 Mar  2  2016 bluetooth*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1275 Jan 20  2016 bootmisc.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2125 Apr 27  2016 brltty*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1904 Nov 18  2015 cgroupfs-mount*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3807 Jan 20  2016 checkfs.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1098 Jan 20  2016 checkroot-bootclean.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  9353 Jan 20  2016 checkroot.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1232 Aug  9 09:32 console-setup.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3049 Apr  6  2016 cron*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2804 Mar 28  2018 cups*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1961 Feb 14  2016 cups-browsed*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2813 Dec  2  2015 dbus*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1195 Oct  7 06:13 .depend.boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2459 Oct  7 06:13 .depend.start
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1926 Oct  7 06:13 .depend.stop
```

and a lot more services when I list,

`ll /lib/systemd/system`

Can someone please tell me why there are so many services running under `init`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only `systemd` running in your system and it is starting all the services, including the ones defined in `/etc/init.d`.

For compatibility with older systems using traditional `init` (also known as "sysvinit" or "System V init"), systemd implements a mechanism by which it is able to start services using the traditional init scripts.

This compatibility layer is implemented by the [systemd-sysv-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysv-generator.html), which looks for legacy init scripts and wraps them into native systemd service units. (For example, it will find `/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon` and create a `/run/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service` wrapper for it, which has an `ExecStart=` that runs `/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon start` and similarly for stop and reload operations, emulating the way legacy init scripts work.)

Some distributions also provide wrappers for executables such as `service` and `chkconfig` providing further compatibility with sysvinit.

In order to check which services are defined for systemd, you can use commands such as `systemctl` (shows all unit files), `systemctl list-units` (shows active units in memory) or `systemctl status service`, which you can use on one of the legacy init services, since it exists in systemd through the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not running services, but executable scripts.